# ASP.Net MVC .cshtml page i hae html dropdowenlist.How i get dropdowenlist in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have simple .cshtml page have one HTML drop down list box  how i get drop down list value in controller.ASP.Net MVC .cshtml page i hae html dropdowenlist.How i get dropdowenlist in controller

Comment: Could you show us the code you have for the view and controller, would help with an answer

Comment: To send data from a view to a controller I recommend POSTing it by way of a form submission.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm())
{                         
            <select>
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
            </select><input type="submit" name="name" value="Save" )}

Comment: hi #3dd the sample coding like this

Answer (score 0):

Possible way to get the Dropdownlistcontents to the controller:
1) selecting all elements in the dropdownlist(possible Jquery) and create and Object(preferably JSON)
2) post the object to controller

Hint: You should not work with pure strings , because MVC tends to do things you don`t expect,if you do not understand it.

Worth a read:
http://vault.lozanotek.com/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx